# Mongo db - How to get two counts from same collection with a single lookup?

Tags: mongodb

I have a working query below:

```
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "watchList",
      as: "watchList",
      let: {
        postId: "$_id",
        userId: userCurrent
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $and: [
              { $expr: {$eq: ["$postId","$$postId"]} },
              { $expr: {$eq: ["$$userId", "$user"]} },
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          $count: "watchCount"
        },
        
      ]
    }
  },
```

The above query gives me a count of two conditions combined in AND:

```
        { $expr: {$eq: ["$postId","$$postId"]} },
          { $expr: {$eq: ["$$userId", "$user"]} },
```

**In addition**, is it possible to get the count of ONLY `{ $expr: {$eq: ["$postId","$$postId"]} }` without doing another lookup ?
So there will be two counts -

**Count 1:**
AND condition for

```
    { $expr: {$eq: ["$postId","$$postId"]} },
    { $expr: {$eq: ["$$userId", "$user"]} },
```

**Count 2:**
Single condition

```
{ $expr: {$eq: ["$postId","$$postId"]} }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this,

- `$group` first match count to `firstCount` and second match count to `secondCount`

```
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "watchList",
      as: "watchList",
      let: {
        postId: "$_id",
        userId: userCurrent
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $group: {
            _id: null,
            firstCount: {
              $sum: {
                $cond: [
                  {
                    $and: [
                      { $eq: ["$postId", "$$postId"] }, 
                      { $eq: ["$$userId", "$user"] }
                    ]
                  },
                  1, 
                  0
                ]
              }
            },
            secondCount: {
              $sum: {
                $cond: [{ $eq: ["$postId", "$$postId"] }, 1, 0]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

Comment: I dont think this will give a count of two conditions combined. ie - `total number where postId matches AND at the same time the userId matches.` Its an AND condition. I am playing with your answer to see if I can get that.

Comment: so its difficult check without looking in to your data and expected result from that data.

Comment: I can explain - If i do this - `["$$userId", "$user"]` it will give me total of all entries by this user for any posts. I have to get the count by this user for one postId. So I have to include an AND condition to also check for postId. Just like in my question I have added ` $and: [`.

Comment: i am still not getting but check my updated answer, have combined both condition in firstCount and user condition in secondCount

Comment: I updated the question with what are the 2 counts. please check.

Comment: I think this will work. I tried almost the same but added 1,0 on both lines. Let me try this.

Comment: works but for anyone in future, there needs to be a comma before `1,`. Thanks much. What is the meaning of 1,0 on the eq line?

Comment: yup thanks its done, glad you have solved your problem.[$cond](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) that is condition if > then and > else, first is our condition, if conditions true then return `1`(then) otherwise `0`(else)

Comment: Ah I see. Learned something new. I can use this to now do other lookups. excellent.!